# jdbc result set metadata: getting physical column names on aliased columns

Tags: jdbc, metadata, jruby

I'm using jdbc to execute query statements (in jruby)

```
# made-up example
sql = "select " +
         "c.type as cartype, " +
         "o.id as ownerid, " +
         "o.type as ownertype " +
       "from cars c " +
         "inner join owners o " +
         "on c.vin = o.vin"
# 'stmt' gotten with jdbc-connection.create_statement() 
result_set = stmt.execute_query(sql)
meta_data = result_set.get_meta_data()
col_count = result_set.get_column_count()
```

I can query the various column aliases (`get_column_name`) and tables (`get_table_name`) for each column through the column indexes, but I also need the actual/physical names of the columns, un-aliased.

How do I get the physical/actual name of column, as it is defined in the schema ("ownerid" column alias is column "id", for instance)?

Comment: As additional information, I'm using a sqlite database.  In this situation the `column_label` and `column_name` functions produce identical information (the column alias).  Could this be due to an implementation difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From tests with other database types, it looks as though this is database+driver specific.  Using mysql `get_column_name` returns the actual/physical column name while `get_column_label` returns the alias.  As an aside, both database types (mysql and sqlite) return the physical table name through `get_table_name`.